# Unit testing Realm + Dagger 2 with Robolectric & Mockito

Tags: android, unit-testing, realm, robolectric, dagger-2

So I am working on this little project that uses Dagger 2 for dependency injection and Realm as a database.

I am unit testing it with Robolectric and Mockito (with Powermock). From previous research (and a lot of pain) I realised testing Realm is pretty laborious, but has been done in the past [here](https://github.com/niqdev/dagger-realm-test).

Now, my project has a very similar setup and structure to the one linked above.

When I run my unit tests, all of them pass except for one that gives me a very cryptic message that looks as follows:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.robolectric.internal.ShadowExtractor.extract(ShadowExtractor.java:5)
at org.robolectric.Shadows.shadowOf(Shadows.java:1190)
at org.robolectric.shadows.CoreShadowsAdapter.getMainLooper(CoreShadowsAdapter.java:37)
at org.robolectric.util.ComponentController.<init>(ComponentController.java:31)
at org.robolectric.util.ComponentController.<init>(ComponentController.java:23)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.<init>(ActivityController.java:40)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.of(ActivityController.java:32)
at org.robolectric.Robolectric.buildActivity(Robolectric.java:82)
at org.robolectric.Robolectric.buildActivity(Robolectric.java:78)
at org.robolectric.Robolectric.setupActivity(Robolectric.java:86)
at uk.co.placona.tradesafe.view.EditActivityTest.ActivityShouldNotBeNull(EditActivityTest.java:54)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl
```

The line of code specified on the error above is:

```
activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(EditActivity.class);
```

The activity exists, and has a TradeRepository injected to it when it starts up.

The activity in question can be found [here](https://github.com/mplacona/trade-safe/blob/master/app/src/main/java/uk/co/placona/tradesafe/view/EditActivity.java) along with the rest of the code. I have been trying to debug this for about 3 days now with no success. Every other unit test I create works fine, except any unit test that is used by an Activity, which makes me think I'm probably missing something really obvious.

Would be happy to clarify any questions here. With many thanks!

Comment: Do you run it with `PowerMock`?

Comment: Yes, as you can see here: https://github.com/mplacona/trade-safe/blob/master/app/src/test/java/uk/co/placona/tradesafe/view/EditActivityTest.java

Comment: Yeah, already checked. It is always tricky with 'PowerMock'

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I'm finding. Saw some suggestions of people saying not to use it, I think at tis point I really need it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

static is evil, powermock is evil :).

I think you should get rid of your class Injector. You don't need it because you have only one CustomApplication object during the lifetime of your application.

You should modify your code as follow:

In CustomApplication.java, the application component is created, set in a field variable, and injected

```
private ApplicationComponent applicationComponent;

public void setup(){
        getOrCreateApplicationComponent().inject(this);
        databaseRealm.setup();
        stethoDebug.setup(this);
    }

public ApplicationComponent getOrCreateApplicationComponent() {
        if (applicationComponent == null) {
            applicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                    .applicationContextModule(new ApplicationContextModule(this))
                    .repositoryModule(new RepositoryModule())
                    .build();
        }

        return applicationComponent;
    }
```

In the methods onCreate of CreateActivity, EditActivity, and MainActivity, Injector is replaced with

```
    ((CustomApplication) getApplication())
            .getOrCreateApplicationComponent()
            .inject(this);
```

In RepositoryModule we will use Dagger 2 to inject dependencies into constructors so we don't need to inject manually the Context and the DatabaseRealm

```
@Provides
@Singleton
public TradeRepository provideTradeRepository(DatabaseRealm databaseRealm) {
    return new TradeRepositoryImpl(databaseRealm);
}

@Provides
@Singleton
public DatabaseRealm provideDatabaseRealm(Context context) {
    return new DatabaseRealm(context);
}
```

then in DatabaseRealm we add a constructor with Context as parameter

```
Context mContext;

RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration;

public DatabaseRealm(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}
```

and same in TradeRepositoryImpl, a constructor with databaseRealm is added

```
DatabaseRealm databaseRealm;

public TradeRepositoryImpl(DatabaseRealm databaseRealm) {
    this.databaseRealm = databaseRealm;
}
```

For RepositoryTestModule, we add databaseRealm as parameter:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
public TradeRepository provideTradeRepository(DatabaseRealm databaseRealm) {
    return isMocked ? mock(TradeRepository.class) : new TradeRepositoryImpl(databaseRealm);
}
```

in your TestCustomApplication we override the getOrCreateApplicationComponent

```
@Override
    public ApplicationComponent getOrCreateApplicationComponent() {
        return DaggerApplicationComponentTest.builder()
                .applicationContextModuleTest(new ApplicationContextModuleTest())
                .repositoryModuleTest(new RepositoryModuleTest(false))
                .build();
    }
```

Now for each of your tests we run them with RobolectricGradleTestRunner and add TestCustomApplication.class as application tag

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 21, application = TestCustomApplication.class)
```

when we need to inject dependencies into ours tests we will inject like this:

```
@Before
public void setupDagger() {
    DaggerApplicationComponentTest.builder()
            .applicationContextModuleTest(new ApplicationContextModuleTest())
            .repositoryModuleTest(new RepositoryModuleTest(false))
            .build().inject(this);
}
```

We still have a NullPointerException in our EditActivityTest because this line:

```
loadTrade(intent.getExtras().getString("ID"));
```

Either you check the intent is not null or you provide one in your test.

Comment: I usually create `Test<MyApplication>` which will be loaded by Robolectric automatically, to avoid having `CustomTestApplication` and duplicating logic to setup injections. But might be the super good idea. I will rethink my approach

Comment: Wooow! You just took me straight to school here Steve! Thank you so much for this. Reading through the code, it makes so much more sense and looks so much cleaner! And yeah.. static.. tell me about it! I wish there was a way for me to +1 this answer a few more times! Such a great and complete answer! Thank you so much for taking the time, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Looking to your test class, I don't see that you use any of **Robolectric** test runners.

You must use `RobolectricGradleTestRunner` or `RobolectricTestRunner` to trigger Robolecric functionality about loading manifest, parsing resources, creating main looper, etc.

If you don't use them, you probably can achieve it with own code in setup, but it is not the usual way, and I'm not sure that many people here can explain to you how to achieve it.

As well, **Robolectric** and **PowerMock** are modifying java `ClassLoader` both. That is why it is so hard (maybe impossible) to get them together working. So check @Steve answer how to modify your code to remove **PowerMock** necessity for your test.

Comment: Thanks Eugen, really appreciate your answer here. I have modified this code in so many ways, I much have changed the runner at some point and didn't even realise it. Know when you start changing everything on a whim to see if anything makes any difference? That was me yesterday :-). Really appreciate your comments and suggestions though!

Comment: You're welcome! Thanks for comment and kudos to @steve-c